# How to get my image to show up in codepen.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used a full page background jquery image plugin called backstretch. After I was done making the site I wanted to add it to codepen.io, but the image for the full page background won't show up.

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>Oregon</title>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Raleway%7cIndie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
   </head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="pics.html">Pics</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="main-content">
        <h1>Vacation In Oregon</h1>
        <a class="oregon" href="http://www.oregon.gov/pages/index.aspx" target="_blank">
            <p>Oregon</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script>
              $.backstretch("https://devinsabbatical.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/3-mount-jefferson.jpg");
    </script>
</body>
```

Can anyone explain to me how to get the image to show up on codepen.io?  If it helps the image is the last part of my html that begins with $.backstrech("https://devinsabbatical.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/3-mount-jefferson.jpg");

Here's a link to my codepen: http://codepen.io/mike316/pen/Vjrjzg

Comment: Did you check your console for errors? (hit F12 on Windows, Opt+Cmd+I on Mac) There's nothing wrong with where your image is saved or CodePen. You aren't loading one of your scripts correctly.

Comment: I just did f12 and everything is okay, nothing showed up in the console on codepen, or when I use f12 on my site on codepen, weird. The plugin works on my computer just fine, it's just when I put the site up on codepen, it won't show the image.

Comment: I don't believe you for a second. If I open my developer tools and look in the console, I see at least one `Uncaught TypeError` or `Object doesn't support property or method 'backstretch'`.

Comment: Dang I wonder what's wrong, why isn't it showing up on my computer.

Comment: What browser are you running? Do you actually see a web console?

Comment: I'm running chrome.

Comment: If you're running Chrome, then you will see [this console with these errors](http://i.imgur.com/5s6lsrO.png) when you press F12.

Comment: I see it now on code pen. Thank you for the help, do you have any ideas on how to fix the error? When I launch the site from notepad++ and hit f12 chrome doesn't say anything in browser, I wonder why the console is saying I have errors on codepen.

Comment: Well, the error is saying that `backstretch` isn't loaded. Why do you think that would happen on CodePen but not on your local computer?

Comment: I have no idea, I'm really new a jquery. I wonder if it's something to do with codepen, because why would the plugin work okay on my computer, but not work at all on codepen.

Comment: Rui Costas answer is correct. If you change the URL from a local one to a CDN one, it works. I've tested it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You need add url to script, not local path:

this is your line: 
`<script src="js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>`

Change to this (on your codepen source): 
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.4/jquery.backstretch.min.js">`

Comment: Nope. Tried it and nothing. It's all good, I'll find something else to use. Between the other clown that tried to comment, "I don't believe you for a minute." This site sucks for getting help. You been cool thought Rui, thank you for trying.

Comment: @GusatvoPacheco thanks but, thats works form me in you code.

Comment: @GustavoPacheco This "clown" was telling you the truth because, as you indicated later, you weren't seeing the error on your *local* copy even though I said to check it on CodePen. This is the correct answer, you just don't understand how to debug a problem or follow instructions.

Comment: @GusatvoPacheco is true what MikeC says.

Comment: Eh, you're still a clown. And  figured out what I did later. You came off as a arrogant jerk, and as I can see, you are.